How to delete unused column table?
I write latex with IEEEtrans with TexLive version 2022.
I would like to have a table in the middle of two columns as follows (combined cell T3, combined cell T4, and text width)

Here is the code:
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!ht]

\captionof{table}{Comparison}

\label{tab:sequence comparison} 
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} { |c | c |c |c |c |}
\hline
  \textbf{\makecell{Place/Transition}} & \textbf{\makecell{Explanation}} & \textbf{\makecell{Holding  time}}  & \textbf{\makecell{X}} & \textbf{\makecell{A}} \\ 
  \hline
  $T_1$  & Unloading wafers from LL & $w$ & $xxxxxxxxxxxxx$ & $aaaaaaaaa$ \\
  \hline
  $T_2$ & Unloading wafers from step 5 & $w$ & $x$ & $a$\\
  \hline
  $T_3$ &  Loading wafers to step 1 & $w$ & $x$ & $a$\\
  \hline
  $T_4$ & Unloading wafers from step 2 & $w$ & $x$ & $a$\\
  \hline
  $T_5$ & Loading wafers to step 3 & $w$ & $x$ & $a$\\
  \hline
  $T_6$ & Unloading wafers from step 4 & $w$ & $x$ & $a$\\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}

Here is the result (there is extra unused columns on the right side).

What do I need to modify the code?
Thank you.

I think it is only possible to place the table on the top of next page (impossible in the middle of a page). And the tabularx env need some X columns with variable width to occupy the total text width.
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{table*}[!ht]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\captionof{table}{Comparison}
\label{tab:sequence comparison} 
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} { | c | >{\centering\arraybackslash} X | c |  >{\centering\arraybackslash} X  | >{\centering\arraybackslash} X |}
\hline
  \textbf{Place/Transition} & \textbf{Explanation} & \textbf{Holding  time}  & \textbf{X} & \textbf{A} \\ 
  \hline
  $T_1$  & Unloading wafers from LL & $w$ & $xxxxxxxxxxxxx$ & $aaaaaaaaa$ \\
  \hline
  $T_2$ & Unloading wafers from step 5 & $w$ & $x$ & $a$\\
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{$T_3$} &  Loading wafers to step 1 & $w$ & $x$ & $a$\\
  \cline{2-5}
   & Unloading wafers from step 2 & $w$ & $x$ & $a$\\
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{$T_4$} & Loading wafers to step 3 & $w$ & $x$ & $a$\\
  \cline{2-5}
   & Unloading wafers from step 4 & $w$ & $x$ & $a$\\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[1-13]
\end{document}


